# Different Read/Write types for FirestoreDataConverter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to use different types for reading and writing data using the `FirebaseDataConverter`?

The typing of `FirebaseDataConverter<T>` suggest that there should only be a single type `T`, which is both what you would get back when querying and what you should provide when writing.

But in the scenario outlined below, I have two types, `InsertComment` which is what I should provide when creating a new comment, and `Comment`, which is an enriched object that has the user's current name and the firebase path of the object added to it.

But there is no way to express that I have these two types. Am I missing something?

```js
type Comment = { userId: string, userName: string, comment: string, _firebasePath: string }
type InsertComment = { userId: string, comment: string }
function lookupName(_id: string) { return 'Steve' }

const commentConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<Comment> = {
    fromFirestore(snapshot, options) {
        const { userId, comment } = snapshot.data(options)
        return {
            userId,
            comment,
            name: lookupName(userId),
            _firebasePath: snapshot.ref.path,
        } as any as Comment
    },
    // Here I wish I could write the below, but it gives me a type error
    // toFirestore(modelObject: InsertComment) {
    toFirestore(modelObject) {
        return modelObject
    },
}
const commentCollection = collection(getFirestore(), 'Comments').withConverter(commentConverter)

// This works great and is typesafe
getDocs(commentCollection).then(snaps => {
    snaps.docs.forEach(snap => {
        const { comment, userName, _firebasePath } = snap.data()
        console.info(`${userName} said "${comment}" (path: ${_firebasePath})`)
    })
})

// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// This gives me the type-error: that fields "userName, _firebasePath" are missing
addDoc(commentCollection, { comment: 'Hello World', userId: '123' })
```

Comment: As mentioned by you,[`FirestoreDataConverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) accepts only single type. I believe it is not possible to use different types for reading and writing

Comment: Or you can define `InsertComment` as type [Partial<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Comment: Thought of that, but then you could create comments without userId. _firebasrPath would be a valid property.

Comment: I believe it is not possible with single converter, either have to use two converter or Partial<Type>

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I don't think this ought to be the way it should be done. It feels hacky.

Basically, I make two DataConverters, one for reading and one for writing.

I make the one for reading the default one, and when I need to write, I overwrite the read-converter with the write-converter.

```js
function createReadFirestoreConverter<T>(validator: Validator<T>): FirestoreDataConverter<T> {
    return {
        fromFirestore(snapshot, options) {
            return validator({ ...snapshot.data(options), _id: snapshot.id, _path: snapshot.ref.path })
        },
        toFirestore() {
            throw new Error('Firestore converter not configured for writing')
        },
    }
}

function createWriteFirestoreConverter<T>(validator: Validator<T>) {
    return {
        fromFirestore() {
            throw new Error('Firestore converter not configured for reading')
        },
        toFirestore(modelObject: any) {
            return validator(modelObject)
        },
    } as FirestoreDataConverter<any>
}

const installedComponentConverterRead = createReadFirestoreConverter(installedComponentValidator)
const installedComponentConverterWrite = createWriteFirestoreConverter(newInstalledComponentValidator)

const readCollection = collection(getFirestore(), `MachineCards/${machineCard._id}/Components`).withConverter(installedComponentConverterRead)

// If I need to write
const docRef = doc(readCollection, 'newDocId').withConverter(installedComponentConverterWrite)
```